# BigQuery using Regex in Javascript UDF escaping dynamic value

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

Im trying to use regex with dynamic variable in BigQuety with JS UDF but there is some problem with the escaping and I don't know how to solve it.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION `replaceRegex`(org STRING, to_replace STRING, replace_to STRING)
RETURNS STRING LANGUAGE js AS
"""
    re_string = `\\b${to_replace}\\b`
    let re = new RegExp(re_string, 'gi');
    return org.replace(re, replace_to);
""";

SELECT replaceRegex('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', 'fox', 'bear')
```

This version does not work.

But I change:
`\\b${to_replace}\\b`
to:

```
re_string = /\\bfox\\b/
```

Then it does work.

But I cant hardcode my regex it has to be dynamic value passed.

Comment: What is the outcome of `console.log(re);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding **r** at the start of your triple quoted string makes your code work as it treats everything as raw strings see this [reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#string_and_bytes_literals). Your code should be:

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION `replaceRegex`(org STRING, to_replace STRING, replace_to STRING)
RETURNS STRING LANGUAGE js AS
r"""
    re_string = `\\b${to_replace}\\b`
    let re = new RegExp(re_string, 'gi');
    return org.replace(re, replace_to);
""";

SELECT replaceRegex('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', 'fox', 'bear')
```

Test:

[image]

Comment: The [BigQuery JavaScript UDFs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#javascript-udf-structure) public documentation has also mentioned the usage of `raw string`.Leaving this here for reference.